WW2 German POW Camp Comedy
I'm looking for an old WW2 comedy movie strongly resembling the general setup of Hogan's Heroes, but with different actors and somewhat more "grounded".
It's been an old black/white movie, most likely from the US, 1960's or a bit later.
It was no "supercut" of Hogan's Heroes and also not M.A.S.H. (I know it's a different war and no POWs), but there was also lots of mischief going on, prisoners tricking guards, etc.
In one remarkable chapter, the prisoners are supposed to repaint road markings, where they immediately start to paint a line similar to old Looney Tunes cartoons, straight out of their own POW camp into some nearby camp for women.

Could it be A Coming-Out Party http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0055593 ?

@dbugger Even if unsure, just post it as an answer. Besides that, this might actually be the one. Trying to find more about it.

Wasn't answer worthy.  Here's the wiki page https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Very_Important_Person_(film)

@dbugger IMO it is. Perfectly fine for an identification question. Describe the movie in a few lines, add the links. I'll have a look tomorrow.

That's Stalag 17 from 1953: http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0046359/.
I think actually Hogan's Heroes was inspired by this movie.
The "Line Painting" scene you mentioned starts here:




You're right. Great movie, though more of a drama with comedic moments than a comedy. Forgot about that scene.

Must've missed this Q. It's one of my favorite Wilder films.

Finally had the chance to watch it and it's indeed that movie, thanks. And yeah, is definitely more serious than what I remembered.
